# Android convert image from path to java.io.File

Tags: android

I'm trying to upload file via `Ion` from android and i want to convert image from path such as `SDCard`, my code can create stream from that, but i cant create `java.io.File` from that, because i get this error:

```
Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.io.OutputStream', required: 'java.io.File'
```

My code:

```
File imageFile = new File(photoPath);
OutputStream os = null;
try {
    os = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Comment: Why line has that error? I mean, in the code above, there's no method whose 2ng argument is a OutputStream..

Answer (score 0):

At this line:

```
os = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
```

You should not pass the file into **FileOutputStream**, instead, open it with file path:

```
os = new FileOutputStream(path_to_file);
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.lang.String)) is the Java documentation.